# Change parent state without rerendering parent, but rerender a child

Tags: reactjs

I'm still fairly new to react and I'm wondering if its possible to do the following.

I have a state that is solely used to transfer information between two disparate child components. The first child is a table (BootstrapTable). When I click the row, an onClick function is called. This function sets the parent state to an array of all currently clicked rows. Then, this information will be passed to the second child, which will allow me to do submit the rows to a backend server for processing. Currently the parent rerender erases the checkmark in the table. And, because I'm using a node module, I cannot control how the table rows acts (before with my custom created table, I was able to set the checkBox state right after receiving new props so I could manually change it back to what it used to be).

The only solution I can see is passing the changed state to the child without rerendering. Is this possible or am I designing this wrong? And if so, what should it be instead?

```
getInitialState : function () {
    return (
        {
            tableData : [],
            selectedRows : []
        }
    );
}

onRowSelect : function () {
    this.setState({selectedRows : this.refs.table.state.selectedRowKeys}, 
        function () {
            console.log('selectedRows are ', this.state.selectedRows);
        }
    );
},
render : function () {
    if (this.state.tableData.length === 0) {
        return (<div>Loading...</div>);
    } else {
        return (
        <div className='full-table'>
            <div className='react-table'>
                <BootstrapTable 
                    ref='table'
                    data={ this.state.tableData }
                    selectRow={ this.getSelectRowProps() }
                    options={ this.getOptions() }
                    insertRow
                    deleteRow
                    search
                    columnFilter
                    hover
                    pagination>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='key' dataAlign='right' hidden={true} isKey={true}>
                        Key
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='in_progress_text' dataAlign='right'>
                        In-Progress
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='payment_id' dataAlign='right'>
                        Id
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='product_code' dataAlign='center'>
                        Type
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='status_description' dataAlign='center'>
                        State
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='payment_amount' dataAlign='center'>
                        Amount
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='payment_currency' dataAlign='center'>
                        Currency
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='process_state' dataAlign='center'>
                        Status
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='process_message' dataAlign='left'>
                        Message
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                </BootstrapTable>
            </div>
            <div className='submit-buttons'>
                    <SubmitButtonContainer selectedRows={this.state.selectedRows} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some code examples.

Comment: Code examples  have been added.

Comment: If you have access to some kind of flux implementation then you could use those to communicate between the components.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering should be idempotent; ie you should be able to re-render the parent (many times even) without affecting anything. It sounds like a problem with some state being managed within React and some state being managed outside of React. React does better when it can own and manage all of the state that affects the things it renders.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean when you say that "some state being manged within React and some state being managed outside of React?" I'm using a table called react-bootstrap-table. Are you saying that perhaps the node module isn't managing children state properly?

Comment: Oh ok so you are doing everything with React. I thought you might be trying to interface with some third party non-react lib. In either case my first statement stands, rendering should not change state.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're actually using the onRowSelect function here but if you are the parent is reaching into the children's state and that is not how you should do things in React. React works with a 'unidirectional data flow', in which data always flows from parent to children. It is likely that this state should live in the parent only and be passed down to the children through props.

Comment: To expand on that, components should never be directly aware of another component's state. Instead a component will share relevant pieces of its state, only to children, through props. If a child needs to change that state, then the parent will provide a function to do so once again with props. The function lives in the parent and so the parent is the only place where state can actually be changed, but the function can be passed in props to children which is what allows children to modify state in parents.

Comment: The reason I am reaching into the child state is to extract which rows's checkboxes have been clicked. That seemed like the correct way to do it according to the react-bootstrap-table API. Barring that, I am not sure how to access the info of whether or not a row has been checked off.

Comment: Where do they recommend doing that? Do you have a link to it in from their docs or examples? I have not used that library but I'm quite surprised that this is their approach to that problem.

Comment: In this particular case, the example is just a getter but if I can use it in that way, I don't see why I can't do what I am doing. Thanks for the help!
http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/advance.html#how-to-get-select

Comment: Wow yeah I guess that's how they built their component. I agree you should probably be able to do that judging by their docs. Perhaps this question is best posted in the github issues for that repo. In any case the question of changing parent state without a re-render goes against how React works. You could probably do it but it would be very kludgy and ill-advised.

Comment: Ultimately I don't think they've designed their component well if they ask you to reach from the parent into the child for information. I am a fan of https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/ for tables like this since it handles arbitrary (large) numbers of rows as well as lets you pass in a row rendering function which means you can basically pass in any data and reference any props you want (such as a selected prop). It is much more idiomatic React.